# Filter data in excel

Tags: excel

I want to get number of people absent for a day from a dump file that has data as follows:

```
Name  |no of hrs |production            |date

ABC   |   6      |    55                |11/26/17
PQR   |   Absent |  Absent              |11/26/17
MNO   |5         |50                    |11/26/17
XYZ   |Absent    |Absent                |11/26/17
```

In this format rest of the data for rest of the days. 
I want to show a recurring graph with  percent of people absent for a week. I am unable to get number of people absent on that particular day. I tried using 'countif'  but it gives me total people absent from the whole dump file. How can I get it day wise (by using functions)

Comment: By using COUNTIF(S) function probably.

Comment: Can you elaborate

Comment: Here's a pseudo-formula where you should update references. `=COUNTIFS(no_of_hours_column,"absent",date_column,date_criterion_cell)`

Comment: Thanks for the help I'll try it and get back to you..

Comment: OK. If I don't respond then I have logged out for the day!

Comment: It works perfectly fine thanks.